# How to install gnome extensions through firefox using Ubuntu-Gnome 14.04.1

Tags: firefox, gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell-extension, firefox-extensions

After fresh install of Ubuntu-Gnome 14.04.1, I was unable to install gnome extensions through the https://extensions.gnome.org/ website. The website would given an error that it could not detect that gnome was installed on my system. I am using the gnome shell package "gnome-shell 3.10.4-0ubuntu5.2  amd64". How do I get the website to recognize gnome on my system so that I can install extensions from gnome.org?

Answer (score 1):

In firefox's menu: *Add-ons* > *Plugins* and select *Always activate* for the *Gnome Shell Integration* plugin.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add an extension to the firefox web-browser.

1. Go to [gnome-them-tweak](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-theme-tweak/) and add this extension to firefox.
2. Restart firefox
3. Go to the page of the extension you want to add [weather extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/613/weather/).
4. You should now see a slider bar to the left of the extension name at the top of the page. You can slide the bar to the left (off to on) to enable extensions from the web browser.
5. Other gnome extensions can be found at https://extensions.gnome.org/.
6. Gnome Extensions can also be added other methods such as the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The Add-on in the Firefox will need to communicate to the Ubuntu so you also need Native Host Connector installed in Ubunut -

1. First Install the Native Host Connector using Following Command , and You can read more [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation)

```
sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell
```

2. Install the Add-on in the Firefox or Chrome ( Whatever you are using )

   - Here is for Firefox - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search
   - Here is For Chrome -  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep